# Type mismatch returning item from LinkedList

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I have an object of class A:

```
public class A
{
    private int num;
    private char color;
}
```

That I'm trying to read into an Array from a LinkedList using the Iterator, like so:

```
public static void main()
{
    LinkedList<A> A = new LinkedList<A>();

    //make some objects of class A

    A.add(A1);
    A.add(A2);
    A.add(A3);

    Iterator it = A.iterator();

    A[] arrayA = new A[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
           > arrayA[i] = it.next();
        }
}
```

The line marked with a `>` in the code above gives me the following compiler error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to A`

I looked this up and thought I was safe from the issue of raw types by instantiating LinkedList to be of type A and that LinkedList would be returning an A, not an Object, but it's still giving me the same compiler error. Why is that?

Comment: Which is line 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify generics of Iterator:

```
Iterator<T> it = A.iterator();
```

Because you have not specified it explicitly, iterator `it` stores raw types (`Object`).

If you don't want to specify genetics (but I definitely recommend to do it) you have to explicitly cast value returned from `it.next()`:

```
Iterator it = A.iterator();


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arrayA[i] = (A) it.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, `it.next();` returns `Object` instance as you haven't specified type at below line

```
 Iterator it = A.iterator();
```

You need to specify generics to return instance of `A`.

```
 Iterator<A> it = A.iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't specify type of iterator, your iterator is raw typed, correct code here:

```
public static void main() {
    LinkedList<A> A = new LinkedList<A>();

    A.add(new A());
    A.add(new A());
    A.add(new A());

    Iterator<A> it = A.iterator();

    A[] arrayA = new A[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         arrayA[i] = it.next();
    }
}
```